# Difference in the meaning between "Sinbad takes a barrel" and "Sinbad takes a barrel with him"?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference in the meaning between "Sinbad takes a barrel" and "Sinbad takes a barrel with him" ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addition of *with him* in this context emphasizes the fact that after Sinbad takes the barrel, he has it close to him for a certain period of time while he journeys in search of water to fill the barrel.

Comment: When I read "Sinbad takes a sweet and gives it to Sally", I interpret it like this.  Sindbad grabbed a sweet by hand. He handed a sweet to Sally. I do not understand how I can hand a sweet to Sally without holding the sweet by hand. I would appreciate a little explanation for me to understand.

Comment: When I read "Sinbad takes a barrel", I interpret it like this, "Sinbad grabbed a barrel by hand". I would appreciate it if you let me know what went wrong.

Comment: Does "Sinbad takes a barrel" means that Sinbad grabs a barrel and then has it close to him? Is the difference in the meaning between “Sinbad takes a barrel” and “Sinbad takes a barrel with him”it that the difference between with " for a significant period of time " and without " for a significant period of time " ?

Comment: @user22046 - Don't try to interpret "Sinbad takes a barrel" apart from its surrounding context. The verb _take_ has [**many**](http://wordnik.com/words/take) possible meanings; figuring out which one is the intended meaning requires the reader to look at the rest of the passage. By itself, "Sinbad takes a barrel" could mean, "Sinbad steals a barrel," "Sinbad grabs a barrel," "Sinbad totes a barrel," or even "Sinbad wins a barrel [as a prize]." Adding the phrase "with him" helps the reader understand which definition is being used.